# JVM unit testing with Mockito for testing Retrofit2 and RxJava for network requests

Tags: android, mockito, rx-java, retrofit2

```
Android Studio 2.3 RC 1
```

I am using the MVP architecture and want to run JVM unit tests.

In my Model I am using Retrofit2 and RxJava to fetch movies from a API. I want to test the function `getPopularMovies(...)` However, this function will make a call to the webserver. However, in the test I want to mock this somehow and just test the `onSuccess()` and `onFailure()` methods are called.

My model class looks like this snippet only to keep it short:

```
public class MovieListModelImp implements MovieListModelContract {

    @Override
    public void getPopularMovies(PopularMovieResultsListener popularMovieResultsListener) {
        mSubscription = mMovieAPIService.getPopular(Constants.MOVIES_API_KEY)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Results>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Timber.d("onCompleted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Timber.e(e, "onError");
                popularMovieResultsListener.onFailure(e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Results results) {
                Timber.d("onNext %d", results.getResults().size());
                popularMovieResultsListener.onSuccess(results);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the interface:

```
public interface MovieListModelContract {
    interface PopularMovieResultsListener {
        void onFailure(String errorMessage);
        void onSuccess(Results popularMovies);
    }
    void getPopularMovies(PopularMovieResultsListener popularMovieResultsListener);
}
```

My problem I am trying to solve is how can I use Mockito to test the `getPopularMovies` without actually calling the network service? I just want to test that:
`popularMoviesResultsListener.onFailure(e.getMessage())` will be called on failure to get movies
and 
`popularMovieResultsListener.onSuccess(results);` will be called on success when movies are recieved

I have a test like this but I am not sure if this is correct:

```
@Test
public void shouldDisplaySuccessWhenNetworkSucceeds() {
    /* Results is the movie results class that is returned */
    Results results = new Results();

    /* Mock the listener */
    MovieListModelContract.PopularMovieResultsListener mockPopularMoviesResultsListener =
            Mockito.mock(MovieListModelContract.PopularMovieResultsListener.class);

    /* Real instance of the model */
    MovieListModelImp movieListModelImp = new MovieListModelImp();

    /* Call getPopularMovies with mock listener - However, this will still make a real network request */
    movieListModelImp.getPopularMovies(mockPopularMoviesResultsListener);

    /* Verify - but I think I have got this all wrong */
    verify(mockPopularMoviesResultsListener, times(1)).onSuccess(results);
}
```

So my problem is how can I mock a call to a network request and test the expected onSuccess() and onFailure() is working correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to complete my answer here. I am not sure if it is the best way and hopefully other people might be able to comment.

For the setup:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MovieListModelImpTest.this);

    movieListModelContract = new MovieListModelImp(mockMovieAPIService);

    RxJavaHooks.setOnIOScheduler(new Func1<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
        @Override
        public Scheduler call(Scheduler scheduler) {
            return Schedulers.immediate();
        }
    });

    /* Override RxAndroid schedulers */
    final RxAndroidPlugins rxAndroidPlugins = RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance();
    rxAndroidPlugins.registerSchedulersHook(new RxAndroidSchedulersHook() {
        @Override
        public Scheduler getMainThreadScheduler() {
            return Schedulers.immediate();
        }
    });
}
```

And the tear down

```
  @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        RxJavaHooks.reset();
        RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().reset();
    }
```

My Service API

```
@GET("movie/popular")
Observable<Results> getPopular(@Query("api_key") String apikey);
```

Mocks

```
@Mock MovieAPIService mockMovieAPIService;
@Mock Observable<Results> mockCall;
@Mock ResponseBody responseBody;
@Mock MovieListModelContract.PopularMovieResultsListener mockPopularMoviesResultsListener;
private MovieListModelContract movieListModelContract;
@Captor ArgumentCaptor<Callback<List<Results>>> argumentCaptor;
```

My test

```
 @Test
    public void shouldDisplaySuccessMessageOnSuccess() {
        final Results results = new Results();
        when(mockMovieAPIService.getPopular(anyString())).thenReturn(Observable.just(results));

        movieListModelContract.getPopularMovies(mockPopularMoviesResultsListener);

        verify(mockPopularMoviesResultsListener, never()).onFailure(anyString());
        verify(mockPopularMoviesResultsListener, times(1)).onSuccess(results);
    }
```

I have given a example of a success case here which works ok as an example. However, as everything seems to work ok. I am just wondering is there a better way of doing it, or is there any mistakes in what I have done?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you have mocked the real network request as is required to unit test your class. I tried to address this in my answer :)

Comment: @PravinSonawane That was my mistake. I pasted the wrong code snippet for the test. I have now updated my answer. Here I am using the when(...).thenReturn. To mock the MovieAPIService.getPopular(..) to return the correct results. Then I verify that the correct onFailure() and onSuccess() have been called the correct number of times. This is just testing the business logic and not making any real calls to the network. The test is independent of any external dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to user `TestSubscriber` to assert in unit tests.

> Return the Observable from Retrofit instead of void

(Note that I have removed the listener `PopularMovieResultsListener` as you are using RxJava. With RxJava you can subscribe to the returned Observable and use `onNext()`, `onComplete()`, `onError()` instead.)

```
public class MovieListModelImp implements MovieListModelContract {

    @Override
    public Observable<Results> getPopularMovies() {
        /** Return the Observable from Retrofit. */
        return mMovieAPIService.getPopular(Constants.MOVIES_API_KEY);
}
```

> Use `TestSubscriber` in your unit tests to assert

```
@Mock
MovieAPIService mMovieAPIService

@Test
public void shouldDisplaySuccessWhenNetworkSucceeds() {

    /* Results is the movie results class that is returned */
    Results expectedResults = new Results();


    MovieListModelImp movieListModelImp = new MovieListModelImp();
    //Mock mMovieAPIService which is the actual network call
    when(mMovieAPIService.getPopular(any(String.class)).thenReturn(Observable.just(results));

    Observable<Results> actualResultsObservable = movieListModelImp.getPopularMovies();
    TestObserver<Results> testObserver = actualResultsObservable.test();
    testObserver.assertSubscribed();

    testObserver.assertResult(expectedResults);

    //verify
    verify(mMovieAPIService, times(1)).getPopular(any(String.class));

}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. However, I would like to keep my listener as its part of my design.

Comment: I have managed to answer my own question and posted here. It works ok for success and failure cases. And I have mocked my listener. Maybe you can comment if you think there is something better I can do.